# WSDL locations for SAP Applications

Tags: sap, web-services

Is there a list or resource available that defines the standard WSDL locations or SOAP messaging parameters for a standard SAP installation ??

In particular, I'm interested in initiation work orders / notifications (IW34) from a third party client (such as a smartphone). I was able to sniff some of the simpler requests using Wireshark but could find any info on this.

P.S: In case you are wondering, our integrators seem incompetent (or reluctant, I can't tell). Their solution to this was to provide a URL to the web based GUI for smartphones.

Comment: Trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are most likely a large number of SAP components that expose web services, but chances are that you want to acesss [SAP Netweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_NetWeaver), which by default expose a web page listing web services: http://host:50000/wsnavigator/enterwsdl.html

This page does however require you to login, so you are going to need a friend in the integration or SAP teams.

Comment: Awesome... will start making friends immediately :-)